# Pass a variable using chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How i can pass a variable with the chrome.tabs.executeScript

this works:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
code: 'var config = 2;'}, 
function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'injector.js'});
});
```

but i want to pass a variable, like

```
var test = e.target.id;

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
code: 'test;'}, 
function() {
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'injector.js'});
});
```